# How Can I Use Tiled In Phaser 3, Using JSON Format?

Tags: phaser-framework, tiled

For a while now, I've been trying to load a json tilemap from tiled into Phaser 3. I have tried many different things from online, but none of them seem to work. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Hi Twickz. In order to help solve this it would be helpful to know what you've tried and what error(s) you've received with the code. As it is now, we won't be able to determine where the issue might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to load your exported map from Tiled to the Json format in the `load` function.

Second, you need to create it in the `create` function with the appropriate methods.

Check out https://labs.phaser.io/index.html?dir=game%20objects/tilemap/&q= in the static sction and let me know